# HQL, Collections & Query Cache - LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am trying to get caching working with a query that has left join fetch (on lazy associations) but I'm getting a `LazyInitianlizationException` when I enable caching on the query.

I tried using `Hibernate.initialize()` on the collections in the `DAO` with no success.

Both entities and collections have the cache annotations.

Shouldn't hibernate use 2nd level cache to load the entities for the collection ids in the query cache?

I do not want to use `OpenSessionInView` filter.

Edit: Hibernate.initialize() in the dao method solved the problem. for some reason the first time round it didn't work. When using queries or criteria, join/fetch profiles are not performed. needs to be done manually. (a little disappointing)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still in transaction when initialization is being performed?

Comment: The service layer is annotated with @transaction.

I'm getting the exception outside the transaction.. I tried initializing the collection in the DAO method but with no results. (both by simply calling the getters and using hibernate.initialize)

Answer (score 0):

When I was checking Hibernate code, it looked like Hibernate cannot reuse cache when using HQL queries (it didn't have compiler from HQL to their caching mechanism).

Read internet about `LazyIntializationException` you'll find possible roots of the problem.

But, frankly I can recommend you rather use [fjorm](https://code.google.com/p/fjorm/). Disclaimer: I'm a founder of fjorm.

Comment: The actual entities were being loaded from cache. The problem was with "joined" entities. Hibernate.initialize solved the problem (collections were loaded from cache)